# Laravel how do I add date picker and also time picker in my form

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to put a date picker and also a time picker in my form. but it went like this [this is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yiHi.png%60<html)

this is the source code

```
   <div style="position: relative">

  <strong>Timepicker:</strong>

  <input class="timepicker form-control" type="">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>

</div>

<div style="position: relative">

  <strong>Date:</strong>

  <input class="datepicker form-control" type="">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>

</div>
```

```
$('.timepicker').datetimepicker({

    format: 'HH:mm:'

}); 

$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({

    format: 'DD/MM/YY'
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more details and your current source code?

Comment: Post the code here as text, not image

Comment: it keeps messing up lol

Comment: haha sorry abt that